# 2-D Matrix In C, realloc not work

Tags: c, matrix

I have a little problem, first of all, sorry for my English, secondly, I'm making a matrix 2-D, but i have a problem with the work memory, I don't understand why it doesn't work. The code is written in C. I want to set one or more strings and save into an array, for this i need to increase the array's capacity dynamically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Create a Struct

```
typedef struct {
 int rows;
 int col;
 int flagPosition;
 int wordBiggest;
 int tamanioString;
} matrixTest;

int insertString( char **matriz );
void rellenarMatriz( char **matriz, char string[], matrixTest *datosMatriz );
int getElementBiggest( char **matriz, int size );
```

Main

```
int main()
{
char *stringg = NULL;

insertString( &stringg );

free( stringg );
return 0;
}
```

In the next function, i initialize the struct and i'm loading the string, this string then i send to another function called 'rellenarMatriz'. Until here it's all fine.

```
int insertString( char **matriz ){

char __string[300];
int i = 0;
int sizeRow = 0;
matrixTest datosMatriz = { 1,1,0,0,0 };

matriz = (char **) calloc( datosMatriz.rows, sizeof(char *));

for (i = 0; i < datosMatriz.rows; i++)
    matriz[i] = (char*)calloc(datosMatriz.col, sizeof(char));

puts( "User say: " );

while( fgets( __string, 300, stdin ) ){
    puts( "User say: " );
    i = 0;
    sizeRow = 1;

    while( i < strlen( __string ) - 1  ){
        if( __string[i] == ' ' )
            sizeRow++;
        i++;
    }

    datosMatriz.tamanioString = strlen( __string ) - 1;
    datosMatriz.rows = datosMatriz.rows + sizeRow;
    datosMatriz.flagPosition = sizeRow;

    rellenarMatriz( matriz, __string, &datosMatriz );
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the problem.. Look at the realloc and calloc functions. I'm going crazy

```
void rellenarMatriz( char **matriz, char string[], matrixTest *datosMatriz){

int i = 0,
    j = 0;

datosMatriz->wordBiggest = getElementBiggest( &string, datosMatriz->tamanioString );

if( datosMatriz->col < datosMatriz->wordBiggest ){

    (*matriz) = realloc( (*matriz), (datosMatriz->wordBiggest) * sizeof( char * ) );

    for( i = datosMatriz->col; i < datosMatriz->wordBiggest; i++ ){
        matriz[i] = calloc( 1, sizeof( char ));
    }
    datosMatriz->col = datosMatriz->wordBiggest;
}

for( i = 0; i < datosMatriz->col; i++ )
    (*matriz) = realloc( matriz[i], ( datosMatriz->rows ) * sizeof( char * ) );

for( i = 0; i < datosMatriz->col; i++ ){
    for( j = datosMatriz->rows-datosMatriz->flagPosition; j < datosMatriz->rows; j++ )
        matriz[i][j] = calloc( 1, sizeof( char )); // Here is the biiig problem. Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
}

for( i = 0; i < datosMatriz->rows; i++ ){
    for( j = 0; j < datosMatriz->col; j++ ){
        printf( "%d and %d\n", i, j );
        matriz[i][j] = 'a';
    }
}

for( i = 0; i < datosMatriz->rows; i++ ){
    puts( "\t" );
    for( j = 0; j < datosMatriz->col; j++ )
        printf( "[%c]", matriz[i][j] );
    puts( "\n" );
}
}
```

This doesn't matter

```
int getElementBiggest( char **matriz, int size ){

int i = 0,
    biggest = 0,
    countWord = 0;

for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    if( (char)(*matriz)[i] == ' ' ){
        if( countWord > biggest )
            biggest = countWord;
        countWord = 0;
    }
    else
        countWord++;
}
return biggest;
}
```

Also if you find a mistake in my redaction in english, please tell me, i'm studing that and would be so good that you correct my syntax.

Comment: `matriz = (char **) calloc(...` Oh, you broke the input.

Comment: `insertString` is wrong. You modify the local variable only. In `rellenarMatriz` you are a whole dimension out of sync. The variable in `main` needs to be `char **`.

Comment: I suggest writing your memory allocation code separately to the code for filling the memory. This makes it easier to debug and maintain the code.

Comment: `__string` is a reserved identifier. You should not use double underscores in your code

Comment: in C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting the returned value just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the casting.   2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as `1`,  Using that expression just clutters the code.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   4) when calling `realloc()`, always set the returned value into a temporary variable, check for NULL before assigning to the target variable. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Cluttering the code makes it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  IF the call to `realloc()` fails, and the target variable is immediately set, then the original memory pointer is overwritten with NULL, which results in a memory leak as that pointer cannot be recovered.

Comment: for ease of readability and understand by us humans, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{',  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.   `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`.   Conversions between `int` and `size_t` runs a risk.  (in `gcc`, use `-wConversion` to have all such problems output by the compiler).   Comparisons between `int` and `size_t` runs a risk.  (in `gcc`, use: `-Wall -Wextra` to have all such problems output by the compiler).

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns the number of characters in a NUL terminated char array, not including the terminating NUL char.  So this line: `datosMatriz.tamanioString = strlen( myString ) - 1;`  should be: `datosMatriz.tamanioString = strlen( myString );`   Similar considerations exist for: `while( i < strlen( myString ) - 1  )`

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with: `while( i < strlen( myString ) - 1  )` You should always consider the edge cases.  I.E. What happens if the user only enters is a space? What happens if the user input contains zero spaces? What happens if the the user enters some consecutive spaces?

Comment: for clarity (and re-usability) it is best to separate the struct definition from the `typedef`.   In this case, the struct definition will need to have a `tag` name inserted, so that `struct tagname` can be used in the `typedef`.  I.E.  `struct tagStruct
{
    int rows;
    int col;
    int flagPosition;
    int wordBiggest;
    int tamanioString;
};

typedef struct tagStruct matrixTest;`

Comment: 'magic' numbers should not be used in the code.  They make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
matriz[i][j] = calloc( 1, 1 );
```

has the target: `matriz[i][j]` referencing a single character in the array `matrix[i]`

That is why the compiler is outputting a warning message

Also, note;  this code block:

```
for( i = 0; i < datosMatriz->col; i++ )
    (*matriz) = realloc( matriz[i], ( datosMatriz->rows ) * sizeof( char * ) );
```

is re-allocating the same pointer over and over and over.

Also, note: this line:

```
free( stringg );
```

only free's the first array, not all the other arrays created by calloc()

Also, note: this line:

```
char *stringg = NULL;
```

is declaring a single pointer,  but it is being used as if it were declared via:

```
char **stringg = NULL;
```

and the problem line in the code is treating it as if it were declared via:

```
char ***stringg = NULL;
```